# dynamic cell when load image from server

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I implemented a tableView on viewController, in this tableview i have a cell i want it to make it dynamic cell, i have an imageView for user profile and label for text, and messageImage if user send picture i success to make a dynamic cell for text but not in image ! anyone help me to solve this problem

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You dont have to worry about the image size, because there is a lot of
>   image size can be. If you set the image to its real size it will make
>   the UI very bad.

**So the best thing will be -**

**1.** Set a image view size like `(100 x 100)` or `(200 x 200)`, make it fixed or as per device screen size.

**2.** Then set the image in the image view in `.scaleAspectFit` mode

I think this will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using both the following delegate methods of UITableViewDelegate

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return <SomeAppropriateValue>
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

UITableViewAutomaticDimension should solve your problem.

Comment: i put it in viewDidload()                                                     tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 542                                              tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: And that is working find for text in the table but not for Images ?

Comment: Add this for the image view being used
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

Comment: i put it in storyboard and still the problem